# ImportError: No module named blog Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.8

I am new  in python i try to create blog in django, when i try to create module by typing python manage.py startapp blog this command

python version : 2.7
django-admin version : 1.8

This is urls.py file

```
url(r'^$', 'logicmindblog.blog.views.index'),
url(r'^blog/view/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html', 'logicmindblog.blog.views.view_post', name='view_blog_post'),
url(r'^blog/category/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html', 'logicmindblog.blog.views.view_category', name='view_blog_category'),
```

In settings.py **INSTALLED_APPS** when i add 'logicmindblog.blog', and try to runserver  It give me error ImportError: No module named blog Django

But when i remove project name and just add **'blog'** in and run server this migration and admin working fine, i can add blog , blog category from admin section

Can anyone help me figure this,
Thanks in advance

```
logicmindblog/
├── blog
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── db.sqlite3
├── logicmindblog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── views.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── manage.py
└── views
    ├── base.html
    ├── index.html
    ├── view_category.html
    └── view_post.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the app name `blog` should be added in **settings.py**

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #Custom Apps
    'blog',
    . . .
    . . .

    #django apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    . . . 
    . . . 
]
```

In **urls.py**

```
from .views import index, view_post, view_category

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index, name='view-blog-index'),
    url(r'^blog/view/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html', view_post, name='view-blog-post'),
    url(r'^blog/category/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html', view_category, name='view-blog-category'),
]
```

Comment: Hasibur, Did it help?? You understood??

Comment: there is already __init__.py all directory, How to run fix this error .

Comment: Create inside main project, main project only have `db.sqlite3` and `manage.py` here just put **__init__.py**

Comment: @MdHasiburRahaman, see the updated answer and follow. It will work.

Comment: Another error cannot import name index, i am following https://www.djangorocks.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-basic-blog-in-django/starting-your-application.html to create my blog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164596/discussion-between-md-hasibur-rahaman-and-astik-anand).

Answer (score 1):

You should use this syntax when defining your urls:

```
from blog.views import index, view_post, view_category

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', index, name='view-blog-index'),
  url(r'^blog/view/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html', view_post, name='view-blog-post'),
  url(r'^blog/category/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html', view_category, name='view-blog-category'),
]
```

Take a look at the Django documentation on this topic: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#url)

Also, note that the official documentation recommends using hypens instead of underscores when naming your url patterns: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)

Edit: as Astik pointed, you don't need to put `logicmindblog.blog` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`, you can just put `blog`.

Comment: When i add this line  from blog.views import index, view_post, view_category same error  http://dpaste.com/04382AF